# I need to reach a php file in remote

Tags: php, ajax, server, ftp, remote-access

I need to know how to manage to reach a php file remotely located inside my server, using an AJAX call.
In my ignorance I opened ports 21 for FTP thinking to reach it in this way but I don't think it's the right method.

Comment: Where's your code then?

Comment: Do you need to get the actual file over FTP or do you need data that the PHP file generates/fetches from a data source?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very precise.
Through an AJAX call I have to reach a specific URL where the webservice.php is located in which there is the connection with the database and the insertion query.
What I need is to know which URL I need to put in the AJAX call to have it call the php file

Comment: @Daan I only need that the php files is called to have a connection with the database. I apologize if I am not very precise but I am not an expert in the field

Comment: @MarkOverton the php file is in the htdocs directory of a shared folder in the server.
It can be accessed through FTP without problems but I don't think that I can make an FTP call through AJAX because in that case I'll need to insert FTP user and password

Comment: What is the exact location of the file on the server, you say in the htdocs, but where is the htdocs folder from the root?

Comment: C:\FTP_DATA\htdocs\webservice.php

Comment: If you need to call the webservice.php located in htdocs use this url localhost/webservice.php

Comment: Yes i know but it's not locally. I have to reach that file remotely

Comment: hi Luigi, welcome to stackoverflow. if you want to retrieve the **result** of the opration of an `php` script do, you can use [AJAX Request](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp). however, if you want to retrieve the **code**, its rather difficult using AJAX as it only talk to websites. which one are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Make an AJAX call with Javascript and reach that php file through the http protocol. The file will be executed by your remote server and the response sent back to you in the client.

Comment: Yes but I don't have any http URL linked with the php file. The only possible solutions that comes in mind is to buy a domain but I don't know if it's a correct solution

Comment: If the server IP is static you could use that. Make sure that your server has php+apache (or whatever) listening to your chosen port (80?). You can't use FTP in order to execute code, File Transfer Protocol only transfers up and down files.